# Nemiro's DropboxLogin form closes inmediately - c#

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the Nemiro's LoginForms library to login with Dropbox, the problem is that when the Login form opens, it closes inmediately returning the IsSuccessfully parameter as false. So it is imposible for the user to login with Dropbox

Any idea of what could be wrong?

This is my code:

```
        var login = new DropboxLogin
            (
                APPKEY,
                APPSECRET,
                returnUrl: "https://oauthproxy.nemiro.net",
                autoLogout: false,
                loadUserInfo: false
            )
        {
            Owner = formOwner
        };

        login.ShowDialog();

        if (login.IsSuccessfully)
        {
            STORE TOKEN
        }
        else
        {
            ERROR
        }
```

It always shows the error

Thank you!!!!

Comment: did you find a solution cause i'm experiencing a simillar problem?